# How do I get a string format of the current date time, in python?

Tags: python, datetime

For example, on July 5, 2010, I would like to calculate the string

```
 July 5, 2010
```

How should this be done?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

You can use the [`datetime` module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) for working with dates and times in Python.  The [`strftime` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) allows you to produce string representation of dates and times with a format you specify.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")
'July 23, 2010'
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p on %B %d, %Y")
'10:36AM on July 23, 2010'
```

Answer (score 51):

```
#python3

import datetime
print(
    '1: test-{date:%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S}.txt'.format( date=datetime.datetime.now() )
    )

d = datetime.datetime.now()
print( "2a: {:%B %d, %Y}".format(d))

# see the f" to tell python this is a f string, no .format
print(f"2b: {d:%B %d, %Y}")

print(f"3: Today is {datetime.datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d} yay")

#4: to make the time timezone-aware pass timezone to .now()
tz = datetime.timezone.utc
ft = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
t = datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz).strftime(ft)
print(f"4: timezone-aware time: {t}")
```

1: test-2018-02-14_16:40:52.txt

2a: March 04, 2018

2b: March 04, 2018

3: Today is 2018-11-11 yay

4: timezone-aware time: 2022-05-05T09:04:24+0000

---

**Description:**

Using the new string format to inject value into a string at placeholder {}, value is the current time.

Then rather than just displaying the raw value as {}, use formatting to obtain the correct date format.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatexamples

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: what does `f` mean in `print(f"3`?

Comment: @lei-yang here is a explanation: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/
it marks the string as f string, and python then looks for { } with code/variables in it, and places the content in the string.  It is the latest python3.6 string formatting addition

Comment: The bottom of this page [https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) lists the placeholders like `%B` and what they represent.

Answer (score 26):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
'July 23, 2010'
```

Answer (score 12):

If you don't care about formatting and you just need some quick date, you can use this:

```
import time
print(time.ctime())
```

Answer (score 3):

With time module:

```py
import time
time.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
>>> 'July 23, 2010'
time.strftime("%I:%M%p on %B %d, %Y")
>>> '10:36AM on July 23, 2010'
```

For more formats: [www.tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Simple

```
# 15-02-2023
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

and for this question use "July 5, 2010"

```
# July 5, 2010
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

Comment: That's not the format requested in the question, is it?